# Benefit of using custom initialize function instead of `__init__` in python

Tags: python, oop, initialization

I was looking into the following [code](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix).

On many occasions the `__init__` method is not really used but there is a custom `initialize` function like in the following example:

```
def __init__(self):
    pass

def initialize(self, opt):
    # ...
```

This is then called as:

```
data_loader = CustomDatasetDataLoader()
# other instance method is called
data_loader.initialize(opt)
```

I see the problem that variables, that are used in other instance methods, could still be undefined, if one forgets to call this custom `initialize` function. But what are the benefits of this approach?

Comment: I know this kind of initialization only from data types/classes which have to (de)serialized; but this does not seem to be the case here, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some APIs out in the wild (such as inside `setuptools`) have similar kind of thing and they use it to their advantage.  The `__init__` call could be used for the low level internal API while public constructors are defined as classmethods for the different ways that one might construct objects.  For instance, in [`pkg_resources.EntryPoint`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v36.4.0/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L2376), the way to create instances of this class is to make use of the `parse` classmethod.  A similar way can be followed if a custom initialization is desired

```
class CustomDatasetDataLoader(object):

    @classmethod 
    def create(cls):
        """standard creation""" 
        return cls() 

    @classmethod
    def create_with_initialization(cls, opt):
        """create with special options."""
        inst = cls()
        # assign things from opt to cls, like
        # inst.some_update_method(opt.something) 
        # inst.attr = opt.some_attr
        return inst
```

This way users of the class will not need two lines of code to do what a single line could do, they can just simply call `CustomDatasetDataLoader.create_with_initialization(some_obj)` if that is what they want, or call the other classmethod to construct an instance of this class.

Edit: I see, you had an example linked (wish underlining links didn't go out of fashion) - that particular usage and implementation I feel is a poor way, when a classmethod (or just rely on the standard `__init__`) would be sufficient.

However, if that initialize function were to be an interface with some other system that receives an object of a particular type to invoke some method with it (e.g. something akin to the visitor pattern) it might make sense, but as it is it really doesn't.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the main benefit is to have more detailed control over the instances you create while providing an 'easy to use' initializer for higher level users?

Comment: I mean, isn't that the goal of the `initialize` method in your code? Wrapping it with a classmethod decorator means the initialization is done in one go, rather than splitting it up into an object creation then calling a separate method to set some values is unneeded verbosity, and unneeded verbosity leads to higher likelihood of creating errors.  Wrapping that into a (well named) classmethod makes the API more clear, easier to understand and use.